# How to remove query string with htaccess (for mobile user after url shortener)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

So I'm using the answer from here to remove the query string: [How to remove GET parameters from url with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848157/how-to-remove-get-parameters-from-url-with-htaccess)
And it works fine in general.

Here are the rules I'm using (in the beginning of the htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \? 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p= 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.r-bloggers.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

BUT...

If I browse using a mobile device to this url:

t.co/6raI2VkTse?amp=1

It will redirect me to this url (and will stay there, without a further redirect, even though it has a url parameter):

https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-handle-cran-checks-with-help-from-r-hub/amp/?p=182189&__twitter_impression=true

If I then refresh, it will redirect me to:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-handle-cran-checks-with-help-from-r-hub/

I've tried adding:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?__twitter_impression=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

(from [here](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/website-tips/htaccess-how-to-remove-a-single-query-parameter-from-a-url/))
But this also didn't help.

I have no idea why this is happening. Any suggestions?!

Comment: Maybe a cached result from earlier attempts? You will need to start debugging, so open your browsers development console and check the requests in the networking tab.

Comment: It's helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118511/htaccess-301-redirect-remove-query-string-qsa